# Extending vector bundles from subvarieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety and let $Y\subset X$ be a smooth subvariety. Given a vector bundle $E$ on $Y$, when can $E$ be extended to a vector bundle $\tilde E$ on $X$? I.e., are there cohomology groups containing the obstructions to extending $E$?

Comment: The first obstruction is that the determinant needs to be in the restriction on Picard groups. For the case $X=\mathbb{P}^2$ and $Y$ a smooth plane curve you can see that this is already a strong restriction.

Comment: In addition to the excellent answers below, there is also SGA2.  However, SGA2 will only extend your vector bundle to a reflexive coherent sheaf that is locally free on a Zariski open subset containing $Y$.  If the rank is one, that forces the sheaf to be a line bundle.  However, this can fail for higher rank.

Comment: And preceding SGA2 there is Grauert's theorem that, in the case (over $\mathbb{C}$) that $\dim{X} > 2$ and $Y$ is an ample divisor, $E$ will so extend as soon as it extends to a vector bundle on a complex neighborhood of $Y$. A generalization in formal geometry appears in SGA2.

Comment: Let we have a complex manifold $X$, containing an analytic subset $A$ of complex codimension
at least two. Let $(E,h) \to K\setminus  A$ be a Hermitian-holomorphic vector bundle such that $F_h \in L^n(X\setminus A)$, then there exists a unique vector bundle $\hat E \to X$ such that $\hat E |_{X\setminus A}\cong E$. See Harris, A., and Tonegawa, Y. Analytic continuation of vector bundles with Lp-curvature, Int. J.
Math. 11 No.l, (2000), 29-40.

Comment: For a relative version of my previous comment on a surjective holomorphic fibre space see Theorem 2.2.  of  http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/mana.19992040103/full

Comment: For topological condition to get extension theorems on bundles see Lemma 5 and Lemma 6 of the paper V. V. Shevchishin , The Ock–Grawert principle for the extension of holomorphic line bundles with integrable curvature
V. V. Shevchishin , Mat. Zametki, 50:5 (1991),  109–119 https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01157706

Comment: A theorem of Siu: Let $X$  is a Stein manifold of dimension at least $3$, $K$ is a holomorphically convex compact subset of $X$ with connected complement, and $E$ is a holomorphic vector bundle on $X\setminus K$, then there is a finite subset $P$ of $K$ such that $E$ extends to a holomorphic vector bundle on $X\setminus P$: See A Hartogs type extension theorem for coherent analytic sheaves. Ann. of Math. (2) 93 1971 166–188. 32.50 and also for details of proof see https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.afm/1485802742(Since Siu didn't prove it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without hypotheses on $Y$ there is no hope to define such obstructions, already for line bundles. A natural hypothesis is to take for $Y$ a (smooth) ample divisor in $X$, of dimension $\geq 2$. In [this paper](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jmsj/1239802165), Fujita gives some cohomological conditions which imply that $E$ extends : $H^2(Y, \mathcal{E}nd(E)(-tY))=0$ for all $t\geq 1$ and $H^p(Y, E(tY))=0$ for all $t\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $0<p<\dim Y$. Be aware that these conditions are extremely strong.

Comment: This has been a while. You mention that $Y$ needs to be a smooth ample divisor. Fujita only mentions non singularity of $X$. Is the assumption of smoothness of the divisor implicit throughout the paper?

Comment: No, I guess I put "smooth" because the OP did so. You are right, Fujita makes no smoothness assumption on $Y$.

Comment: Does Fujita assume the divisor is irreducible or maybe a different definition of ampleness? Because I'm considering the case when everything is affine, the cohomologies vanish because cohomology of affine schemes vanish. By Hartshorne's definition any divisor on affine scheme is ample. Then it implies you can extend any vector bundle from any effective divisor. Which is not correct.

Comment: I think he is implicitly assuming that $X$ is a projective variety. His Lemma 3.2 is obviously false in the affine case.

Answer (score 5):

An obvious obstruction comes from topology: the Chern classes of your 
bundle should be obtained from restriction of Hodge classes on an ambient variety. This is (more or less) enough to extend a smooth bundle $B$ 
from $Y$ to $X$. To be precise, you need the classifying map from $Y$ to the space $BU(r)$ to be extendable to a continuous map from $X\supset Y$ to $BU(r)$, where $r$ is rank $B$. This is not the only obstruction, because a way to find a holomorphic bundle with prescribed $(p,p)$-Chern classes on $X$ amounts to a result which is much stronger than the Hodge conjecture (and false, generally speaking). The easiest obstruction to finding a bundle with prescribed $(p,p)$-Chern classes comes from the Bogomolov inequality: for any stable $B$, one has 
$$\int_M [2rc_2(B) - (r - 1)c_1(B)^2]\wedge \omega^{n-2}> 0,$$
where $n$ is dimension of your manifold $M$, and $\omega$ its Kahler form
(case of unstable bundles is considered separately using the Jordan-Holder filtration). Also, if this inequality is non-strict, $B$ admits a projectively flat connection, and therefore $c_2$ and the rest of Chern classes are powers of $c_1$.